# Icon theme "Adwaita" not found - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, okular, icon-themes

I have installed Okular using `snap` in my Ubuntu 14.04. It is functional but there seems to be a problem with some of the icons. They are not being displayed. I have run okular from terminal by:

```
snap run okular
```

and it displays these error messages:

```
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Icon theme "Adwaita" not found.
```

From a little search that I have conducted, these icons are from the Adwaita theme and can be installed from the package `adwaita-icon-theme` or `adwaita-icon-theme-full`. However, none of them are available for Trusty (at least on the standard repositories).

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Comment: There is adwaita icon theme provided by GNOME team on GitHub, though I'm not sure how to apply it so the okular can run without any problem. Check if interested https://github.com/GNOME/adwaita-icon-theme/

Comment: I am in the same thoughts as you. I have checked that repository on github, but I am not sure, how to install it from source and if it is going to work with Okular.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem on xfce. Okular searches for "adwaita", while /usr/share/icons/ has "Adwaita". Adding a soft link to Adwaita fixed it.

```
cd /usr/share/icons
sudo ln -s Adwaita/ adwaita
```